# Android AwesomePlayer: Unexpected abortPrepare. Notify listener of error

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I get this error when trying to start a video with a VideoView on a Sony Ericsson Xperia ray OS vers. 2.3.4. The video playback works just fine on both Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 and Nexus 7 4.1.1/4.1.2. Any thoughts ? Thanks !

LE: It also works on Nexus S 4.1.1.

LE2: I've just tried it with a Galaxy S with 2.3.4. It still doesn't work. Result is below.

LE3: The same error applies to a xx.mp3 file. :|

LE4: When I put the same file on the SD card and play it from there, it runs just fine...

Sony Ericsson Xperia 2.3.4 result:

```
10-15 16:09:05.269: D/VideoActivity(4509): onCreate
10-15 16:09:05.269: W/Resources(4509): Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0065 a=1 r=0x7f0b0065}
10-15 16:09:05.319: D/VideoActivity(4509): onResume
10-15 16:09:05.599: D/MediaPlayer(4509): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-15 16:09:05.609: I/StagefrightPlayer(138): setDataSource('https://xxxx.mp4')
10-15 16:09:05.629: I/AwesomePlayer(138): Unexpected abortPrepare. Notify listener of error.
10-15 16:09:05.629: E/MediaPlayer(4509): error (1, -2147483648)
10-15 16:09:05.649: D/dalvikvm(4509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 254K, 45% free 4092K/7367K, external 10147K/12195K, paused 3ms+6ms
10-15 16:09:05.659: I/ActivityManager(250): Displayed com.xx.yy/.view.activity.VideoPlayerActivity: +450ms
10-15 16:09:05.659: E/ResourceType(4509): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
10-15 16:09:05.659: E/ResourceType(4509): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
10-15 16:09:05.669: W/KeyCharacterMap(4509): No keyboard for id -1
10-15 16:09:05.669: W/KeyCharacterMap(4509): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-15 16:09:05.709: E/MediaPlayer(4509): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-15 16:09:05.709: D/VideoView(4509): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Galaxy S 2.3.4 result:

```
10-15 17:20:47.329: D/VideoPlayerActivity(7086): onCreate
10-15 17:20:47.356: W/ResourceType(7086): Entry identifier 0xcc is larger than entry count 0xac
10-15 17:20:47.372: D/VideoPlayerActivity(7086): onResume
10-15 17:20:47.454: D/dalvikvm(7086): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 633K, 52% free 3637K/7431K, external 14286K/14649K, paused 25ms
10-15 17:20:47.513: I/MediaPlayer(7086): uri is:https://xx.mp4
10-15 17:20:47.513: I/MediaPlayer(7086): path is null
10-15 17:20:47.513: D/MediaPlayer(7086): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-15 17:20:47.517: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): Client(105) constructor
10-15 17:20:47.517: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): Create new client(105) from pid 7086, url=https://xx.mp4, connId=105, audioSessionId=133
10-15 17:20:47.517: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): setDataSource(https://xx.mp4)
10-15 17:20:47.517: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): player type = 1
10-15 17:20:47.517: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84):  create PVPlayer
10-15 17:20:47.528: V/PlayerDriver(84): PVSuspensionState struct constructor
10-15 17:20:47.528: V/PVPlayer(84): PVPlayer constructor
10-15 17:20:47.528: V/PVPlayer(84): construct PlayerDriver
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): constructor
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): OpenCore hardware module not found
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): start player thread
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): startPlayerThread
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): InitializeForThread
10-15 17:20:47.540: V/PlayerDriver(84): OMX_MasterInit
10-15 17:20:47.544: I/ActivityManager(129): Process com.android.vending (pid 7297) has died.
10-15 17:20:47.548: V/PlayerDriver(84): OsclScheduler::Init
10-15 17:20:47.548: V/PlayerDriver(84): CreatePlayer
10-15 17:20:47.634: V/PlayerDriver(84): AddToScheduler
10-15 17:20:47.634: V/PlayerDriver(84): PendForExec
10-15 17:20:47.634: V/PlayerDriver(84): OsclActiveScheduler::Current
10-15 17:20:47.634: V/PlayerDriver(84): StartScheduler
10-15 17:20:47.634: V/PVPlayer(84): send PLAYER_SETUP
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 2
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=1
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/AudioSink(84): AudioOutput(133)
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84):  setDataSource
10-15 17:20:47.638: V/PVPlayer(84): setDataSource(https://xx.mp4)
10-15 17:20:47.642: I/PlayerDriver(84): PlayerDriver::isProtectedFile(https://xx.mp4)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/PlayerDriver(84): File EXT is : .mp4
10-15 17:20:47.642: E/PlayerDriver(84): PlayerDriver::it is a not Protected file
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] setVideoSurface(0x33c00)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/PVPlayer(84): setVideoSurface(0x33c00)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] setVideoSurface(0x396f8)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/PVPlayer(84): setVideoSurface(0x396f8)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] setAudioStreamType(3)
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] prepareAsync
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/PVPlayer(84): prepareAsync
10-15 17:20:47.642: V/PVPlayer(84):   data source = https://xx.mp4
10-15 17:20:47.653: V/PlayerDriver(84): Send player code: 3
10-15 17:20:47.653: V/PlayerDriver(84): handleSetDataSource
10-15 17:20:47.661: V/PlayerDriver(84): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension
10-15 17:20:47.661: E/OsclDirectFileIO(84): [LargeFileSupport] OsclDirectFileIO::OpenFileOrSharedFd Error = -1
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: 26
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] notify (0x6aff0, 200, 1, 26)
10-15 17:20:47.665: W/MediaPlayer(7086): info/warning (1, 26)
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PlayerDriver(84): CommandCompleted
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PlayerDriver(84): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE status=-4
10-15 17:20:47.665: E/PlayerDriver(84): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info -4
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(84): [105] notify (0x6aff0, 100, -4, -4)
10-15 17:20:47.665: E/MediaPlayer(7086): error (-4, -4)
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PVPlayer(84): run_init s=-2147483648, cancelled=0
10-15 17:20:47.665: V/PlayerDriver(84): HandleInformationalEvent: 27
10-15 17:20:47.665: W/PlayerDriver(84): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
10-15 17:20:47.696: E/ResourceType(7086): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
10-15 17:20:47.700: E/ResourceType(7086): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
10-15 17:20:47.700: W/KeyCharacterMap(7086): No keyboard for id -1
10-15 17:20:47.700: W/KeyCharacterMap(7086): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-15 17:20:47.771: I/MediaPlayer(7086): Info (1,26)
10-15 17:20:47.774: E/MediaPlayer(7086): Error (-4,-4)
10-15 17:20:47.774: D/VideoView(7086): Error: -4,-4
```

Comment: You are certain that the device has network access?

Comment: Yes. Of course I have checked.

Comment: It might help if you show `ffmpeg -i` output on the file, in case it's an issue with an unsupported codec or format.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do that. What do I have to do more precisely ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that the respective videos were using HTTPS links.
After switching to plain HTTP, they worked.

Also, I observed that using empty spaces in the video link instead of %20 also caused an error. This also happened only on 2.3.4 and not on 4.1.1. So be sure to look for that as well.